# How to serve node_module files to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm trying to figure out of if there is a feature or convention I'm missing for referencing a js file from a node_module in the client html via `script`. For example, I have `underscore` installed via npm and use it on the server side, but also want to use `underscore-min.js` in the client. Right now i symlink the file into my expressjs static folder, but that seem hacky.

Is there an official or at least cleaner way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`underscore-min.js` really has nothing to do with node. It's a distributed file for serving to clients. My advice is to copy it out of the module into any static serving location you want. It may feel hacky to have 2 copies of the same file, but it's not. You may even want them to be updated separately.

Comment: So npm modules have no blessed way of exposing their files to be served by node as static files. Well, just wanted to make sure that copying the file was the proper way to do it.

Comment: seems kind of hacky. Why does npm have client modules like angular if there no way of getting it to the client?

Answer (score 4):

You can try [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and put all your js files (Node modules) in a folder, for more details checkout his awesome article:

http://substack.net/posts/24ab8c/browserify-browser-side-require-for-your-node-js